# ionic cloud Push notification does not receiving while sometimes on ios device

Tags: ios, ionic2, cloud

I have configured the security profile and install push plugin ,register the push plugin was success

```
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {

     return this.push.saveToken(t);

}).then((t: PushToken) => {

     //return success token
     console.log(t);

});
```

And also I am receiving push notification successfully after that i have added following code

```
//handle push 
this.push.rx.notification().subscribe((msg) => {

         let postID = msg.payload["item"];
         //Goto feed page with arg
         this.app.getRootNav().push(FeedPage, {postId:item});

});
```

Now I am not getting push notification.is there any wrong?